# How to find the singular values of an orthogonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

If you have a orthogonal matrix, say $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{nxn}$ how do you find its singular values?

Comment: They are all 1.  You have the decomposition $A=AII$ which is an SVD decomposition of $A$ as the product of an orthogonal, a diagonal, and an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: Is this using the fact that $ A^T=A^{-1} $ and $AA^T=I$

Comment: Yes.  You assume $A$ is orthogonal.

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Comment: Is there any way to find the singular values using the square roots of the eigenvalues?

Comment: In your problem statement, when you say  "orthogonal matrix $A$" do you mean "square matrix $A$" or "matrix $A$ for which $A^{-1}=A^T$"?  I might have misunderstood you here; you should edit your question to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: The definition of orthogonal that i am using is $AA^T=A^TA=I$, so i believe the second statement is the one i'm trying to use to solve this problem.

Comment: I like as well the characterization of the singular values of $A$ as the eigenvalues of $A^\top A$. Since $A^\top A$ is equal to $I$ for an orthogonal matrix, the result follows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is know that the $n\times n$  matrix $A$ obeys $AA^T=I$, then the singular values of $A$ are all equal to $1$.  Because we can write an SVD decomposition $A=PDQ$ where $P$ and $Q$ are orthogonal and $D$ diagonal, namely by taking $P=A$, $D=I$, and $Q=I$.  Since the identity matrix $I$ is both diagonal and orthogonal, and since $A$ is assumed orthogonal, we know the factorization  $A=AII=PDQ$ is a valid singular value decomposition.  The singular values of $A$ are thus the diagonal elements of $D=I$, namely $1$.